# Accessing UtcTimeStamp from Python via SWIG

Tags: c++, python, timestamp, swig, quickfix

I guess this is a python vs SWIG question more than anything else...

I'm using a C++ package with SWIG Python bindings.
One of the objects I receive is a UTC time stamp from which I'm trying to extract the time stamp.

The object has the following characteristics:

```
>>> print type(obj)
<type 'SwigPyObject'>

>>> print dir(obj)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__hex__', '__init__', '__int__', '__le__', '__long__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__oct__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'acquire', 'append', 'disown', 'next', 'own']

>>> print obj
<Swig Object of type 'UtcTimeStamp *' at 0x0379F320>
```

How do I extract the data out of it?

---

**UPDATE:**
I've found the [UTCTimeStamp](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_utc_time_stamp.html) class which is derived from a [DateTime](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/struct_f_i_x_1_1_date_time.html) struct - it is part of the open source [QuickFix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/) package.

However I still don't know how to access the data. DateTime has simple getter functions such as getYear() - however, how do I access them?

Comment: Did you figure out what c function in your library could take the timestamp pointer from you?

Comment: no I'm still a bit at a loss on how to continue...

Comment: Once you `import quickfix` you should be able to find the right way to call by looking at `quickfix.__dict__` then the `__dict__` of the class (in case I got the capitalization wrong or something) in my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `qfTimeField.getValue()` on the time field, use `qfTimeField.getString()`, and then just `strptime()` the resulting string. For example:

```
qfSendingTime = fix.SendingTime()
message.getHeader().getField(qfSendingTime)
my_datetime = datetime.strptime(qfSendingTime.getString(), '%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, and is what I do myself. However, you should be aware that `strptime` can fail in certain cases. This is a known bug in python involving multithreading, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309650/python-importerror-for-strptime-in-spyder-for-windows-7 When this happens you can workaround by just calling `qfSendingTime.getString()` and forgetting about `strptime`. Then cast your date string into a different type when you need to use it for something

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `obj.getYear()`? It appears from the documentation that `UTCTimeStamp` derives from `DateTime`, so you should be able to access methods of the parent class.

If that doesn't work, what kind of object do you get if you do `newobj = obj.next()`? Did you try `print obj.__doc__?`

Edit: from http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn27a:

> This pointer value can be freely passed around to different C functions that expect to receive an object of type ... The only thing you can't do is dereference the pointer from Python.

So you need to pass it to a wrapper for a C++ function that can take a `DateTime`. I don't know specifically what that is, as I don't know what you're wrapping.

In this case, that is http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/struct_f_i_x_1_1_utc_time_stamp_convertor.html. I believe, although I can't test this, that you call it with:

```
import quickfix
converter = quickfix.UtcTimeStampConverter()
string = converter.convert(obj)
```

Comment: yes, I've tried obj.getYear() and received: `AttributeError: 'SwigPyObject' object has no attribute 'getYear'`

Comment: `print obj.__doc__` returns `Swig object carries a C/C++ instance pointer`